# SQL Server query executing slowly from remote website

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My team and I are experiencing a bit of a mystery, and all of our investigations have turned up nil. I'm hoping that someone on SO might provide us with additional avenues to explore.

I have a website that executes a query and displays results. When this website is on my development machine or Test server, it is excruciatingly slow, to the point where it often times out.

When I publish the website the db server, the query execution time is fast.

The payload of the query is only about 10-15k, so the size of the resultset shouldn't be impacting performance like this.

Our network admin indicates that the db server and the test server are on the corporate lan, which has wide open access to everything on the lan.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might impacting query performance? We're all a bit flummoxed. I can open the connection fine, but as soon as I try to fill a data table with my adapter, things stall:

```
using (SqlConnection cnSource = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ToString()))
        {
            cnSource.Open();                

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnSource))
            {
                adapter.Fill(records); /*** THIS LINE IS SLOW REMOTELY ***/
            }
```

- Edits: About 100 or so records, 4 columns across
- The query, fwiw, is:

The Query is:

```
SELECT ef.Name AS EventFrame, ef.StartTime, efa.Name AS EventFrameAttribute, 
    CAST(efs.Value as String) as AttrValue 
FROM [Reporting].[EventFrame].[EventFrame] ef
    INNER JOIN [Reporting].[EventFrame].[EventFrameAttribute] efa ON efa.EventFrameID = ef.ID 
    INNER JOIN [Reporting].[Data].[EventFrameSnapshot] efs ON efs.EventFrameAttributeID = efa.ID
WHERE ef.StartTime >= N'{0}'
    AND (efa.Name =N'ProductCategory' or efa.Name =N'ActualCases' or efa.Name=N'Target') 
    AND ef.EventFrameTemplateID=N'9b616c78-7ad3-47a1-a5ae-26d299beb50c'
ORDER BY ef.Name, ef.StartTime, ef.EndTime, efa.Path, efa.Name", 
             start.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-CA"))
```

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: How many rows are returned?

Comment: Display the Query that you are using to get data...

Comment: Have you put a trace on the database server to determine if it's executing the query quickly? What if you execute the query via SSMS from your desktop? IOW, what have you done to isolate various elements of the chain?

Comment: Yes, the query is executing quickly on the server. If I use SSMS, or any other client, from a remote machine, it takes a very long time for the resultset to come across the wire.

Answer (score 0):

Try experimenting with different server addresses in connection string. I’ve had a case where sql statements were performing extremely slowly when referenced as (local) but performed normally when I used IP address 127.0.0.1

Comment: Nice suggestion, unfortunately after giving it a whirl, we're still getting slow performance.